# Exclude columns from INSERT

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

long time reader, first time writer. I'm just starting to use the Entity Framework and I've successfully bound a SQL table to a grid (more specifically a Telerik RadGrid).

I've auto generated the model based on the table, and all the CRUD operations work, however, I generate various columns such as 'ID', 'CreatedOn' etc directly in the database based on default values. Performing a trace in SQL shows that the Entity Framework is assigning default values to these columns.

Is there a way to specifically exclude columns from being INSERTED / UPDATED, and if so, will it cause further problems when the new record has these columns created in the database, i.e. will the EF return the data from the database and bind it to the grid, or just the default data it's sent.

Comment: Which EF version is this? Please use the appropriate tags.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Miky exactly what I was looking for!